# Gnuplot: How to use multiple values from one data column?

Tags: function, awk, gnuplot, lines

I've got a multi collumn data file. Let's say I need to only plot the 4th number from the 13th line. This works well with the following piece of code:

```
plot 'datafile' u (some fix x-value):($0==13? $4 :1/0) with points
```

Now I would like to plot the average of these numbers from the 13th and from the 11th line.
Something like this:

```
plot 'datafile' u (some fix x-value):( ($4(line11)+$4(line13.))/2 ) with points
```

As far as I know theres no way to address both lines in gnuplot, right?
Can I use awk or sed in gnuplot to do it? Maybe to store value from line 11 in a variable that can be used in a function of line 13?

Thank you very much in advance for your kind help!

Best wishes,
Tob

Comment: I havent used gnuplot for a longer time but it was always a bad choice for complex dataprocessing (see their [faq](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html#SECTION00075000000000000000) ). I've used simple scripts (python or octave in such circumstances, sometimes grep/awk) and have one original `datafile` and several derived files, eg. `datafile_average`. Make is your friend ;)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used gnuplot in a very, VERY long time and all I really remember about it is that I used to rely pretty heavily on awk to parse the data files. To get the 4th "number" (I assume you mean field/column) from the 13th line in awk would just be:

```
awk 'NR==13{print $4}' datafile
```

and to get the averages of the values from the 4th field in the 11th and 13th lines would be:

```
awk 'NR~/^(11|13)$/{sum+=$4} END{print sum/2}' datafile
```

Now if someone can tell you how to use awk's output in gnuplot (sorry, I just don't remember) then you're in business.

EDIT: a quick google of gnuplot and awk showed up this:

```
gnuplot> plot "<awk '{x=x+$2; print $1,x}' file1.dat" with boxes
```

from http://security.riit.tsinghua.edu.cn/~bhyang/ref/gnuplot/datafile3-e.html plus several other examples. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can also do something with gnuplot only.

**Option 1:**
Extract the values of interest via `stats` and `every`.

- `stats` calculates some statistical values min,max,mean, etc. from one or two columns (check `help stats`)
- `every` limits the range to certain row or block numbers, here: to a single row, i.e. the row of interest (check `help every`)
- hence, in this limited case min, max and mean will all be the same and equal to the value of interest

**Option 2:**
Remember the values within the actual plot command with help of ternary operator and serial evaluation (check `help ternary`, `help operators binary`)

- initialize the values `v1` and `v2` to`NaN`.
- if you get to the rows of interest (`$0==row1-1` and `$0==row2-1`), assign the values to `v1` and `v2` (check `help pseudocolumns`)
- only if `v1` and `v2` are both different from `NaN` do your calculation and plot this value. Check [gnuplot: How to compare to NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54126142/7295599)

In the following example, from column 4 the average of the values in row 11 (here: `11.4`) and row 13 (here: `13.4`) should be plotted, which is `12.4`.

Keep in mind that line/row numbering in gnuplot starts from 0.

This script can easily be adapted to other variations.

**Data:** `SO13456636.dat`

```
 1.1    1.2    1.3    1.4
 2.1    2.2    2.3    2.4
 3.1    3.2    3.3    3.4
 4.1    4.2    4.3    4.4
 5.1    5.2    5.3    5.4
 6.1    6.2    6.3    6.4
 7.1    7.2    7.3    7.4
 8.1    8.2    8.3    8.4
 9.1    9.2    9.3    9.4
10.1   10.2   10.3   10.4
11.1   11.2   11.3   11.4
12.1   12.2   12.3   12.4
13.1   13.2   13.3   13.4
14.1   14.2   14.3   14.4
```

**Script:** (works with gnuplot >=4.6.0, March 2012)

```
### do some math with two values from the same row
reset

FILE = "SO13456636.dat"

myCol  = 4
myRow1 = 11
myRow2 = 13

set grid x,y
set key noautotitle

set multiplot layout 2,1

    # Option 1
    stats FILE u myCol every ::myRow1-1::myRow1-1 name "v1" nooutput
    stats FILE u myCol every ::myRow2-1::myRow2-1 name "v2" nooutput
    plot  FILE u (1):((v1_min+v2_min)*0.5) w p pt 7 lc rgb "red"

    # Option 2
    plot v1=v2=NaN FILE u (1):($0==myRow1-1 ? v1=column(myCol) : 0, \
                               $0==myRow2-1 ? v2=column(myCol) : 0, \
                          (v1==v1 && v2==v2 ? (v1+v2)*0.5 : NaN)) w p pt 7 lc rgb "blue"
unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]