# gnuplot: How to compare to NaN?

Tags: gnuplot, nan

There are several topics here about this (in javascript, c++,...), but haven't yet found one for gnuplot.

Basically, I want to replace "nan" with "---" in labels.

I know that I can set `NaN = "---"` but then `NaN` behaves like a string and other code needs to be adapted.

```
### How to compare to NaN?
NaN = GPVAL_NaN  # default value for NaN

a = NaN
print (a==NaN ? "---" : sprintf("%g",a))
print (a==NaN ? sprintf("%g",a) : "---")
print (a!=NaN ? "---" : sprintf("%g",a))
print (a!=NaN ? sprintf("%g",a) : "---")

a = 123
print (a==NaN ? "---" : sprintf("%g",a))
print (a==NaN ? sprintf("%g",a) : "---")
print (a!=NaN ? "---" : sprintf("%g",a))
print (a!=NaN ? sprintf("%g",a) : "---")
### end of code
```

The result:

```
NaN
---
NaN
---
123
---
123
---
```

So, none of the combination does the job.

Finally, I found that the following seems to work.

```
print (a/a == 1 ? sprintf("%g",a) : "---")
```

My questions:

Will `a/a` always be exactly `1` or could there potentially be rounding errors in special cases?
Is this "the" way how to do it or did I overlook anything?

Comment: argh, I overlooked the "obvious" (or not so obvious) `print (a == a ? sprintf("%g",a) : "---")`

Comment: If you need that in a `plot` command, exactly for the string "NaN" (and not anything that may evaluate to NaN, you could also use `plot ... using ...:(strcol(3) eq "NaN" ? "---" : strcol(3))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just for the sake of not letting this question appearing unanswered...

Probably, the easiest way to compare if a variable `a` is `NaN` or not (at least in gnuplot) and do something with it:

```
print (a == a ? sprintf("%g",a) : "---")
```

Following some discussions on some programming languages here on SO, people are debating about `NaN==NaN` or `NaN!=NaN` or neither of them.

And in case of comparison to the string `"NaN"` in data: see @Christoph's comment above.