# Gnuplot: How to make stats consider records with less data points than expected?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a data file whose records are composed by a timestamp, and one or two data points.

When I run `stats <datafile> using 2:3`, the x values in the records with one data point are ignored.

Example data file:

```
$ echo '1 10 1
2 20 2
3 50
4 40 4' > test.dat
```

and Gnuplot invocation:

```
$ echo 'stats "test.dat" using 2:3' | gnuplot 2>&1 | grep Maximum

  Maximum:           40.0000 [2]        4.0000 [2]
```

I can run two separate `stats`:

```
$ echo 'stats "test.dat" using 2
stats "test.dat" using 3
' | gnuplot 2>&1 | grep Maximum

  Maximum:           50.0000 [1]
  Maximum:            4.0000 [1]
```

This works, however, is there a more idiomatic way to do it?

(additionally, in some cases, when running the second `stats`, I need to ignore the ranges, via `stats stats [*:*][*:*]`)

Comment: Please explain what values you are hoping to obtain from the `stats` command (or commands). Otherwise there is not enough information to answer this question.

Comment: So, I understand you have 3 columns and in the 3rd column some points are missing.
When using `stats ... u 2:3`, apparently, values in column 2 as x are ignored if there is no  corresponding y value in column 3. But when using `stats ... u 2` and `stats ... u 3`, all values of column 2 are taken into account. Fine. So, what's the point?

Comment: @theozh Correct, that's the case. I'm simply asking if there is a more idiomatic way to perform this task, for example, if this is regulated by a global option or so. For example, when performing the second stats, I need to ignore the ranges set by the first `stats` invocation.

Comment: I'll add an example to make it clear.

Comment: Still of interest? Problem solved?

Comment: @theozh smart choice to remind me - I lost track of this topic :) thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me again summarize your issue:
If you want to extract the maxima of column 2 and 3 via `stats $Data u 2:3`,
gnuplot will ignore those lines which don't have a 3rd column. Hence, depending on the data you might miss the absolute maximum in column 2.

If you insist on using only a single `stats` command, you can do the following:

- initialize `ymax = NaN`
- first check whether you have a 3rd column or not. Check `help valid`.
- check if the value in column 3 is not `NaN` and `ymax` is still `NaN`, then initialize `ymax=$3` (see: [gnuplot: How to compare to NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54126142/7295599))
- in a serial evaluation check if the current value of column 3 is larger than current `ymax` and if it is the case assign `ymax=$3`. Check `help operators binary` (serial evaluation) and `help ternary`.
- assuming that you always have a 2nd column, the `stats u (..., $2)` command will effectively run on column 2, hence `STATS_max` will hold the maximum of the second column.

Overall, what is easier: running `stats` twice, i.e. `stats $Data u 2` and `stats $Data u 3`, or the script below?

**Script:**

```
### get maxima from partly empty columns with a single stats command
reset session

$Data <<EOD
-1  NaN
 0    5   NaN
 1   10   1
 2   20   2
 3   50
 4   40   4
 5   30   3
EOD

ymax = NaN
stats $Data u (valid(3) ? ($3==$3 && ymax!=ymax ? ymax=$3 : 0, $3>ymax ? ymax=$3:0) : 0, $2) nooutput

print STATS_max, ymax
### end of script
```

or in a single line:

```
ymax = NaN; stats $Data u (valid(3) ? ($3==$3 && ymax!=ymax ? ymax=$3 : 0, $3>ymax ? ymax=$3:0) : 0, $2) nooutput;
```

**Result:**

```
50.0 4.0
```