# gnuplot: what should sgn(NaN) be?

Tags: gnuplot, nan, signed

I just stumbled accross the following:

If you type

```
print sgn(NaN)
```

The result will be `0`.

gnuplot help says:

> The sgn(x) function returns 1 if its argument is positive, -1 if its argument is negative, and 0 if its argument is 0. If the argument is a complex value, the imaginary component is ignored.

However, `NaN` is not positive, not negative and not 0.
I would have expected the result `NaN`.
Can anybody comment on this and explain?

Comment: I am not aware of any standard that covers this.  sgn() is not in the standard math library for either C or C++.  Note that currently the gnuplot implementation returns an integer. In order to return NaN the return type would have to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ethan comments, if there might not be a common standard, probably everybody defines this to his needs.
Well, then I simply have to define my own sgn(x) function.

This brings me to how to compare to `NaN`, see [gnuplot: How to compare to NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54126142/7295599)

**Code:**

```
mysgn(x) = x==x ? sgn(x) : NaN

print mysgn(999)
print mysgn(0)
print mysgn(-999)
print mysgn(NaN)
```

**Result:**

```
1
0
-1
NaN
```