# Get line number where first occurrence of a value appears?

Tags: bash, awk, gnuplot

I have a CSV file like below:

```
E   Run 1   Run 2   Run 3   Run 4   Run 5   Run 6   Mean
1   0.7019  0.6734  0.6599  0.6511  0.701   0.6977  0.680833333
2   0.6421  0.6478  0.6095  0.608   0.6525  0.6285  0.6314
3   0.6039  0.6096  0.563   0.5539  0.6218  0.5716  0.5873
4   0.5564  0.5545  0.5138  0.4962  0.5781  0.5154  0.535733333
5   0.5056  0.4972  0.4704  0.4488  0.5245  0.4694  0.485983333
```

I'm trying to use find the row number where the final column has a value below a certain range. For example, below `0.6`.

Using the above CSV file, I want to return `3` because `E = 3` is the first row where `Mean <= 0.60`. If there is no value below `0.6` I want to return `0`. I am in effect returning the value in the first column based on the final column.

I plan to initialize this number as a constant in `gnuplot`. How can this be done? I've tagged `awk` because I think it's related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another awk. You could initialize the default return value to var `ret` in `BEGIN` but since it's 0 there is really no point as empty `var+0` produces the same effect. If the threshold value of 0.6 is not met before the `END`is reached, that is returned. If it is met, `exit` invokes the `END` and `ret` is output:

```
$ awk '
NR>1 && $NF<0.6 {    # final column has a value below a certain range
    ret=$1           # I want to return 3 because E = 3
    exit
}
END {
    print ret+0
}' file
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: If you change `print ret` to `print ret+0` you can get rid of the BEGIN section.

Answer (score 4):

In case you want a *gnuplot-only* version... if you use a file remove the datablock and replace  `$Data` by your filename in " ".

***Edit:*** You can do it without a dummy table, it can be done shorter with `stats` (check `help stats`). Even shorter than the accepted solution (well, we are not at code golf here), but additionally platform-independent because it's *gnuplot-only*.
Furthermore, in case `E` could be any number, i.e. `0` as well, then it might be better
to first assign `E = NaN` and then compare `E` to `NaN` (see here: [gnuplot: How to compare to NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54126142/7295599)).

**Script:**

```
### conditional extraction into a variable
reset session

$Data <<EOD
E   Run 1   Run 2   Run 3   Run 4   Run 5   Run 6   Mean
1   0.7019  0.6734  0.6599  0.6511  0.701   0.6977  0.680833333
2   0.6421  0.6478  0.6095  0.608   0.6525  0.6285  0.6314
3   0.6039  0.6096  0.563   0.5539  0.6218  0.5716  0.5873
4   0.5564  0.5545  0.5138  0.4962  0.5781  0.5154  0.535733333
5   0.5056  0.4972  0.4704  0.4488  0.5245  0.4694  0.485983333
EOD

E = NaN
stats $Data u ($8<=0.6 && E!=E? E=$1 : 0) nooutput

print E
### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
3.0
```

Actually, OP wants to return `E=0` if the condition was not met. Then the script would be like this:

```
E=0
stats $Data u ($8<=0.6 && E==0? E=$1 : 0) nooutput
```

Comment: Èven shorter: `plot E=0 $Data u ($8<=0.6 && E==0 ? E=$1 : 0)`

Comment: @Friedrich, right, I overlooked this one... you can use `E` itself as flag...

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
awk 'NR>1 && $8<.6 {print $1;fnd=1;exit}END{if(!fnd){print 0}}' yourfile
```

Comment: or better: `'NR>1 && $NF<.6 {n=$1;exit} END{print n+0}'`

Comment: This always returns zero; could it be because of the column names as the first row? Perhaps it is reading "Mean" as `<0.6`.

Comment: When you say "returns zero" do you mean "outputs 0" or "exits with status 0"? Unix tools don't "return" anything (or if they do then what they "return" is actually their exit status given the keyword used in shell functions to set their exit status), they just produce output and set an exit status, so I just want to make sure which it is you mean as I don't see how that script could always output 0 but it will always exit with status 0.

Comment: @EdMorton I guess I'm not sure. The output to console is `0`, whether or not this means a exit code of `0` or `awk` outputs `0`, not sure. In any case, I was able to resolve it by adding `-F "\"*,\"*"` after `awk`. It turns out it wasn't handling commas.

Comment: It means awk is outputting `0`. You'd have to do `echo "$?"` to see the exit status. You don't have any commas in the sample input you posted so it's not a huge surprise that none of the answers expect them in your input.

Comment: @EdMorton you're right, I should have been more declarative. Cheers.