# Is it possible to read in the data from a file to a gnuplot array?

Tags: gnuplot

Is there a way to load data from a file into a Gnuplot array?
I am working with a program that provides the data and calls gnuplot internally to create a plot. Now I am trying to set the xrange that the upper limit is set where the data in the second column finally approaches zero.
I have googled a lot and tried different methods. Unfortunately without success. The most promising but still not working approach seems to me to import the data and store it in an array. An excerpt from the code is provied below:

```
stats '<datafile>' using 1:($2/1000.) nooutput
array myarray[STATS_records]
do for [i=STATS_records:0:-1] {
  stats '<datafile>' using 1:($2/1000.) index i nooutput
  myarray[i] = STATS_min_y
}
```

The stats expression in the loop causes an error because no values are found.
Thank you in advance for your suggestions or alternative solutions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! How does your data look like? Ok, two columns, but does it have empty lines or double empty lines? Please describe the structure of your datafile and give a minimized example. Furthermore, it looks like you want to reverse the data order, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your current question title and code snippet I assume you want to read data reversed into an array.

> Now I am trying to set the xrange that the upper limit is set where the data in the second column finally approaches zero.

This sentence makes me think that maybe there is more behind which you don't show and which can maybe solved also without arrays. Maybe we are running into a [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

The following script reads a column of a data file reversed into an array.

**Data:** `SO76218289.dat`

```
 1    1.0
 2    2.1
 3    3.2
 4    4.3
 5    5.4
 6    6.5
 7    7.6
 8    8.7
 9    9.8
10   10.9
```

**Script:** (requires gnuplot>=5.2.0)

```
### read data from file reversed into array
reset session

FILE = "SO76218289.dat"

stats FILE u 0 nooutput     # get number of rows
rowCount = STATS_records
array A[rowCount]           # set array size

stats FILE u (A[int(rowCount-$0)] = $2) nooutput

print A
### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
[10.9,9.8,8.7,7.6,6.5,5.4,4.3,3.2,2.1,1.0]
```

**Addition:**

Actually, it was a bit of a xy-problem: You asked for putting data into an array, but the actual goal was to limit the xrange to the range where `y>0`. This can be done simpler. Using the ternary operator (check `help ternary`) the x-values will be set to `NaN` if `y<0`. A value of `NaN` will not be plotted and considered for the x-autorange. Hence, in the example below the x-range is automatically limited to `[3:7]`. If the y-values might get below zero within the limited range and you nevertheless want lines drawn down to zero, the script needs to be adapted.

**Script:**

```
### limit xrange to data y>0
reset session

$Data <<EOD
 1   -1.0
 2   -0.5
 3    0.5
 4    3.0
 5    2.0
 6    1.0
 7    0.5 
 8   -0.1
 9   -0.5
10   -1.0
EOD

plot $Data u ($2>0 ? $1 : NaN):2 w lp pt 7 lc "red" notitle
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition 2:**

Just to illustrate, you can also limit the data to an x-range where `y>0` and including the first sequence of `N` values `y<=0`. This requires `stats` and a more difficult statement to understand using ternary operators and serial evaluation (check `help operators binary`). The final limitation will be done by `every` (check `help every`).

**Script:**

```
### limit x-range to values with y>0 and N values y<=0
reset session

$Data <<EOD
 1   -1.0
 2   -0.5
 3    0.5
 4    3.0
 5    2.0
 6    1.0
 7    0.5 
 8    0.0
 9    0.0
10    0.0
11   -1.0
12   -2.0
EOD

N  = 3             # max. number of y-values <0 in a sequence
n0 = n1 = NaN
c  = 0
stats $Data u ($2>0 && n0!=n0 ? n0=$0 : $2<=0 && n0==n0 && n1!=n1 ? c=c+1 : c=0, c==N ? n1=$0 : 0) nooutput
print n0,n1

plot $Data u 1:2 every ::n0::n1 w lp pt 7 lc "red"
### end of script
```

*Some explanations:*

- first `n0` and `n1` are initialized to `NaN` and `c=0`.

What is the meaning of:

```
($2>0 && n0!=n0 ? n0=$0 : $2<=0 && n0==n0 && n1!=n1 ? c=c+1 : c=0, c==N ? n1=$0 : 0)
```

- if `y>0` and `n0` is `NaN` (see [gnuplot: How to compare to NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54126142/7295599)) then set `n0` to the current line index `$0` which will be the first time `y>0`.
- else if `y<=0` and `n0` *is not* `NaN` and `n1` *is* `NaN`, increase the counter `c` by 1, else reset the counter to `c=0`.
- if `c` is equal to `N` set `n1` to the current line index `$0`.

In summary: `n0` contains the line index with the first time `y>0` and `n1` contains the line index when `y` was `N`-times `<=0` (but only after `n0` was set to some value).
When you plot the data, you simply limit it via `every ::n0::n1`.

The example will limit the x-range to [3:10] because the last N=3 y-values are y<=0.

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your addition. This seems to be a much simpler solution and it is very helpful. You are probably right that it was an xy problem to a certain degree. I will try to avoid this mistake in the future. 
Nevertheless, it seems to me that my solution offers more flexibility. For example, if I want to include the first n values that are zero. However, I may have to work more with the ternary operators to understand them and their possibilities better.

Comment: @ManuelHochheim yes, ternary operators are often _very_ helpful. Your (new) challenge to display the first n zero values as well could also be achieved without arrays (with `stats` and some counter). But I agree, arrays can also be useful in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for. But maybe it is helpful for others when I publish a more extended code snippet to clarify what I was trying to do:

```
FILE = '<datafile>'

stats FILE u 0 nooutput

rowCount = STATS_records

array A[rowCount]

stats FILE u (A[int(rowCount-$0)] = $2) nooutput

do for [i=1:rowCount-1] {
  if (int(A[i]) > 0) {
     xoffset = rowCount - i
     break
  }
}

stats '<datafile>' u 1:($2/1000) nooutput
xmin = STATS_min_x
xmax = STATS_min_x + xoffset

# Set ranges and ticks
set xrange [xmin:xmax]

plot '<datafile>' using 1:($2/1000.)
```

With my code I try to find the point where my data column just contains zero values. It adjusts the xrange accordingly.
This works for me. But if you know a better version please let me know. I would be glad to learn from you and improve my gnuplot skills.

Comment: Ok, so I get a bit better idea what you actually want to do. But still needs some guessing, my understanding now: you have some data and you want to limit the xrange such that the y-values are larger than `0`, correct? What if the y-values go below and above zero several times?

Comment: It is correct that I want to limit the xrange such that the y-values in the tail of my data are larger than 0. Values less than zero are not relevant in my case since I know that my values are always greater equal to zero.